# Perl Hash of Subfunctions

Tags: perl

I wish to have a hash containing references to sub-functions where I can call those functions dependent upon a user defined variable, I will try and give a simplified example of what I'm trying to do.

```
my %colors = (
    vim => setup_vim(),
    emacs => setup_emacs(),
)

$colors{$editor}(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

where `setup_vim()` and `setup_emacs()` would be sub-functions defined later in my file and `$editor` is a user defined variable (ie vim or emacs). Is this possible? I can't get it working, or find good information on the subject. Thanks.

(Note I have it implemented right now as a working Switch, but I think a hash like the above would make it easier to add new entries to my existing code)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here is the syntax.

```
my %colors = (
    vim => \&setup_vim,
    emacs => \&setup_emacs,
);

$colors{$editor}(@args)
```

Note that you can actually create functions directly with

```
my %colors = (
    vim => sub {...},
    emacs => sub {...},
);
```

And if you're familiar with closures, Perl supports full closures for variables that have been declared lexically, which you can do  with my.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, got it working fine. I'm not sure what closures are I'm self learning Perl by reading Mastering Perl (Foy) and they are 2-3 chapters away :)

Comment: Closures also work on the other kinds of lexical variables, not just on those created with `my`.

Comment: @tchrist: Yes, closures work with all lexical variables.  But the things people want to use them for don't as obviously happen with our variables.  Still I have updated my response.

Comment: @btilly: I was kinda thinking of `state` variables, too, although those are of limited utility; they really only work with scalars.

Comment: @tchrist: Ah.  I've never had occasion to use state variables, so didn't think of them.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for pointing out `state` variables, one more thing to put in my Perl arsenal

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a reference to the subroutine you want to call into the hash.

Here's an example:

```
sub myFunc {
   print join(' - ', @_);
}

my %hash = ( key => \&myFunc );
$hash{key}->(1,2,3);
```

With \&myFunc you get the reference wich points at the function. Important is to leave the () away. Ohterwise you would pass through a reference to the return value of the function.

When calling the function by reference you have to derefence it with the -> operator.

Comment: "When calling the function by reference you have to derefence it with the -> operator." False.

Comment: @Chris: It was once true.  It now is not.

Comment: @tchrist - True. It hasn't been true since I learned Perl (three years?).

Comment: @Chris Lutz, @tchrist, I know that you can use "the arrow rule" from perlreftut in this case because it is contained in a hash so you already have one subscript and the () being the second you can drop the -> however if you have `perl -E '$sub = sub { say "Hello" }; $sub->();'` don't you need the `->`? You need the arrow unless you are in the special case of the function reference being in a hash (and other related "Arrow rule" cases)

Comment: @Joel - Sort of. You only need it to get it from a plain scalar. `$array[0]{hash}($function_call)` works. You can take it out between the array/hash index and function call operators, even if thoseoperators aren't dereferencing a reference.

Comment: @Joel: You can always call it the good old-fashioned way: `&$sub()` or `&{ $hash{$key} }()`, which even worked in Perl4.