# Creating a hash of subroutines, and run one

Tags: perl

I'm trying to replicate the solution given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893834/55366) example.

The code is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
  one => sub { print 'one'; },
  two => sub { print 'two'; },
);

$hash{one};
```

The error I'm getting when running this is:

> Useless use of hash element in void context at t.pl line 9.

I've made a running example [here](http://codepad.org/F1HP3HH7).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Use `$hash{one}();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it's not a symbol defined in a sub, you need to tell perl that it's a code reference explicitly to get it to 'run' it - otherwise you have just got a code reference to an anonymous hash, which you're trying to use in a void context.

You can do this by:

```
$hash{one}->();
```

Or:

```
&{$hash{one}}();
```

Or:

```
$hash{one}();
```

Comment: The `&{...}` form works but should be avoided because it forwards the current arguments – similar to `$hash{one}(@_)`. An explicit function call is better.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Will avoid the &{...} then.

Comment: `$hash{one}()` is identical to `$hash{one}->()` except that Perl allows closing brackets `)`, `}`, `]` to be followed immediately with any opening bracket `(`, `{`, `[`  with the appropriate dereferencing. Some people choose to make the indirection specific with intervening arrows `->`,  even surrounded with spaces. My choice is to remove them, as well as any other unnecessary non-whitespace characters, as far as possible as it speeds up my comprehension of code dramatically.

Comment: Re "*similar to `$hash{one}(@_)`*", ...but more dangerous, because changes to `@_` in the called sub will affect `@_` in the calling sub too.

Comment: changed the & version to have parens

Answer (score 0):

`$hash{one}()` is identical to `$hash{one}->()` except that Perl allows closing brackets `)`, `}`, `]` to be followed immediately with any opening bracket `(`, `{`, `[`  with the appropriate dereferencing

Some people choose to make the indirection specific with intervening arrows `->`,  even surrounded with spaces

My choice is to remove indirection arrows `->`, as well as any other unnecessary non-whitespace (I'm claiming *"darkspace"* here!) characters, as far as possible as it speeds up my comprehension of code dramatically

You can load and play with this code as much as you like

```
use strict;
use feature ':5.10';

my $s = [ 1, 2, 3 ];

my $subs = {
    aa => sub { [0, $s, 0] },
    bb => sub {  99 },
};

say $subs->{aa}()[1][1];
```

#### output

```
2
```

I personally think that's clearer than something like this

```
say $subs -> {aa} -> () -> [1] -> [1]
```

which takes too much scanning to read in one pass. But I would be grateful for any comments that encourage a different view

Comment: To my eyes `$subs->{aa}->()->[1]->[1]` is more readable than `$subs->{aa}()[1][1]`. It's easier for me to exactly see the number and kind of dereferences.

Comment: @tinita: Thank you for that. I wondered whether explicit indirection arrows would be preferred by people who are less familiar with Perl, but it seems not as you are undoubtedly familiar with the language. But don't single spaces suffice? For instance `$subs->{aa} () [1] [1]` saves three characters, and six if the arrows are space-wrapped.

Comment: I prefer the dereference arrows for uniformity between the first and subsequent subscripts, and dislike spaces between subscripts as they falsely suggest low operator precedence. And that's what I think is great about Perl: it gives you choices to express yourself clearly, instead of trying to prescribe the one true style (Java, Python). Note that outside of golfing, the number of characters is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @amon: *"Note that outside of golfing, the number of characters is mostly irrelevant"* That isn't true, at least for me; it's the biggest reason why COBOL is so hated, with statements like `PERFORM 20000-MAIN VARYING WS-POSN FROM WS-FIRST BY 1 UNTIL WS-POSN > WS-LAST`. I'm sure you prefer `for` to `foreach` in Perl? A single statement needs to be physically small enough that the whole thing is readable without shifting your gaze, allowing you to comprehend the whole thing in a single glance. Conversely, blank lines, if used properly, help the reader to focus on sets of related statements.